# Algebraic version of a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, group-isomorphism

I'm wondering if there is anything like a manifold that incorporates isomorphisms instead of diffeomorphisms. That could be a topological space that locally is isomorphic to a group, but not globally.

I could think of some problems arising, but my knowledge of algebra is rather sparse. What do you think ?

Comment: Well there's schemes, which are spaces that locally look the space of prime ideals of a ring.  So checking that two schemes are isomorphic is equivalent to looking at charts and checking that the corresponding rings are isomorphic.